# length of the Hard disk ID and interpreting it

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wmi

I am using Hard disk ID to generate License key for my software. In my machine i am getting 15 character length ID. Is this length of the Hard disk ID constant for all manufactures or varies between them?

Is there any accepted method to interpret the hard disk ID?

Thanks,
Regards,
Robo.

Comment: What if a user has no harddisk? I think that's still a supported configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it varies. See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx for an example. Note that if a user changes their hard drive, it's going to invalidate their license so you need a process for dealing with that. Note also that people using emulators (WINE?) *might* not get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

No it varies, I have length of harddisk ID as 8.